# unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str' in python pandas

Tags: python, data-science

[image]

I have a data set and I am trying to slice my data using `loc`

when I am running the code I am getting error

> unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

can you please help me on this

```
sample.loc[(sample.First_name == ('Ankur' & 'Mudassir')), ('age','City')]
```

I want to select 2 names or multiple name and want their other info like age and city

when I a am using single name the code is working

[image]

but whenever I try 2 or more name it is giving an error. I know there are multiple way to do this but I want to know why this error is coming.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can your share a sample of your dataframe ?

Comment: Please share sample dataframe Have you tried with && `sample.loc[(sample.First_name == ('Ankur' && 'Mudassir')), ('age','City')]`

Comment: @Prathik tried && but not working. data frame added

Comment: @AlexandreB. shared dataframe

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for...

```
sample.loc[lambda d: d.First_name.isin(['Ankur', 'Mudassir']), ['age','City']]
```